# Change Scala auto formatting style for a block lambda

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Let us have a code like this:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list.foreach(a => println(a))
```

When converting from parentheses to braces (inspection `Convert to a block expression`), IntelliJ IDEA formats code like this by default:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list.foreach {
  a => println(a)
}
```

I would prefer following format instead:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list.foreach { a =>
  println(a)
}
```

Are there some settings for indenting, braces, lines and spacing which would achieve this?

Comment: I checked Intellij style config (preferences -> editor -> code style -> scala)  and did not find this particular option.

Comment: it is called "convert to block expression" so it's not special to lambdas, it's more general, converts any parens around anything to braces, so I doubt you can easly modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be already posted as a bug report before, which now seems to be fixed in [SCL-6486 'Convert to block expression' should respect codestyle](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6486).